# Select the count of columns with values with specific name for the columns

Tags: python, sql

My table(car_mileage) structure is like this.

[image]

No of cars column (**car_Number**) will be dynamically populate and will vary depending on different persons.

I need the sql query which gives the count of car_Number columns whose values are more than 0 for a particular name.

example for Joseph - count is 10
for Jose   - count is 8

Please Help

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you had a table like `user_cars`, where each user has a number of rows corresponding to their cars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--I think it can do in multiple solution. one of this is 
-- SQL Server statement
SELECT name,age,County,
CASE WHEN car_1>0 then 1 else 0 END + CASE WHEN car_2>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 + ... + CASE WHEN car_n>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ColumnsCountIsMoreThenZero
FROM MyTable
```